# How to debug Xamarin iOS ERROR MT2002 in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This app should get a data from MySQL server and show it, but I am getting this error:

> MTOUCH: error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Configuration.ConfigurationException" reference from "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Comment: it sounds like you're using a library that references System.Configuration, which does not exist in Xamarin

Comment: Jason, how would you find said library?

Comment: It is generally recommended to use a Web API to get data from an SQL (or MySQL) server and then have your mobile app to connect to the Web API, this way you do not have to expose your MySQL server to the internet at large, which can be a security issue. IOW the MySQL server can only be accessed by the server hosting your Web API, thus the Web API acts as a security layer so hackers cannot see your MySQL server directly and the Web API can prevent any SQL hacks to your MySQL server. Going this route would likely also resolve the above error.